# Doctrine Migrations failes on reserved keywords

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm, doctrine, migration

I am using Doctrine Migrations by using the standalone PHAR package.
The CLI seems to fail over Mysql reserved keywords:

```
./doctrine-migrations migrations:status

[PDOException]                                                                                                                                                                                                   
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL     syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LINES' at line 1
```

Here my database contains a table named `LINES` which is a reserved keyword.

Is there a way to work around this?

Comment: why don't you change the table name?

Comment: @raygo I prefer having Doctrine Migrations to be able to deal with reserved keywords the correct way, over of refactoring excisting code to reflect a change in table name...

Answer (score 2):

If you are going to use reserved words, put them in quotes:

```
/** @Column(name="`number`", type="integer") */
private $number;
```

I would recommend you not to use reserved words if you don't have to though!

Comment: Doctrine Migrations CLI seems to list the tables in the db, which is where it probably goes wrong. I have no control over this functionality, i.e. I can not put the quotes as it is not my code that is executed...